# Estimating an image deblurring/denoising technique

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise, blurry

I'm new to image processing and wanted to deblur/denoise some images using **Matlab**. Example:

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

I don't know the exact blurring/noising effects by which the second image came about. At first, I normally did so by trial and error of the [Wiener deconvolution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvwnr.html) method, but not able to reach best results.

**So my question is, is there a more clever method other than trial and error?**

(Note: The output image was obtained from Robot36 radio transmission decoder.)

Comment: This is a _very_ active research topic in Computer Vision. I suggest to search Google for "blind deconvolution cvpr", and look at the papers on the listed researchers, especially Anat Levin (http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/)

Comment: I'll definitely give it a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying the Richardson-Lucy deblurring algorithm. It is available as a built-in function in the Image Processing Toolbox. It makes use of multiple iterations which you can set to control the degree to which you want the image deblurred. I've always found this a very useful method. Here's the doc link: [deconvlucy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvlucy.html)

Comment: Great, but how do I deduce the PSF itself? Or is it arbitrary? I have gone through convolution methods, but not PSF sadly, so forgive my ignorance on that part! I went online to check for it, but couldn't find a clear way to obtain it.

Comment: I would suggest trying to recreate the blur using the fspecial function (which is nothing but generating the PSF). You can massage the parameters a bit, and see what fits your blurred image best. I realize this is rather arbitrary, but it may just work. Has worked for me before.